# Kick command for batch chat program

Tags: batch-file

i am working on a batch chat program... because it's fun.. but i have run into a problem.

I want the users to be able to chat, or use commands from the same prompt and this method works:

```
set /p m=Message: 
set tm="%m%"
if %tm% == "KICK" goto kick
echo %time% ^<%u%^>: %m% >> %log%
```

However to make the command work i need to have another step somewhere else in the batch file:

```
:kick
set /p person=Who to kick? 
del %dir%\%person%
```

How can i make it so that someone can just type "KICK John" to kick someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /p m=Message: 
set tm=%m%
if /i "%tm:~0,4%"=="KICK" goto kick
echo %time% ^<%u%^>: %m% >> %log%


:kick
set person=%tm:~5%
if not defined person set /p person=Who to kick? 
if not defined person goto kick
del %dir%\%person%
```

Naturally, the destination label for the final `if not defined` is debatable.

---

Fix : remove quotes surrounding `%m%`

---

Additional 20130924T0736Z

Here's my test batch:

```
:: @ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET u=whatever
SET log=u:\log.log

set /p m=Message: 
set tm=%m%
if /i "%tm:~0,4%"=="KICK" goto kick
echo %time% ^<%u%^>: %m% >> %log%

TYPE %log%
GOTO :eof

:kick
set person=%tm:~5%
if not defined person set /p person=Who to kick? 
if not defined person goto kick
ECHO del %dir%\%person%
GOTO :EOF
```

And run-report:

```
>SETLOCAL

>SET u=whatever 

>SET log=u:\log.log 

>set /p m=Message:  
Message: 
>set tm=Hello Friend :P 

>if /I "Hell" == "KICK" goto kick 

>echo 15:33:12.77 <whatever>: Hello Friend :P  1>>u:\log.log 

>TYPE u:\log.log 
15:33:12.77 <whatever>: Hello Friend :P 

>GOTO :eof
```

So - given that I've no idea of what your setting for `u` or `log` or `dir` happens to be, and that it works for me as shown above, I can only conclude that the quotes ARE required somewhere in the rest of your code - which you haven't shown.

There's no ban on using your quotes - once the presence of "kick" is determined, so

```
set tm="%m%"
```

directly after the `IF /i...` line should fix your problem.

Comment: When i try to use the command with, or without a name, I get:

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Problem is that when you remove the quotes, if you type a message that has a space in it, eg: "Hello Friend :P" it will say  "Friend :P was unexpected at this time." and go to regular command prompt.

Comment: Ah thank you! Yeah, my code had different commands, I didn't know that all the commands at to have "if /i "%tm:~0,4%"" etc. Works perfectly now :P

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try this:

```
Setlocal Enableextensions
set /p m=Message: 
set tm="%m%"
if /i %m:~0,4% == "KICK" call kick "%m:~4%"
echo %time% ^<%u%^>: %m% >> %log%

:kick
del %dir%\%1
goto :eof
```

Im not too familiar with this sort of Batch scripting (I'd normally use C#), but that should work fine. Tell me if it doesn't work, along with the errormessage. There are other ways of doing it as well.

Mona

Comment: When using this method it acts as if KICK isn't a command. It will just send "KICK Balls" to the chat.